# Strange behaviour in Wordpress admin

Tags: posts, wp-admin

A few weeks ago, I had to move my blog due to a failing hard drive. It was running on an old server, and I took the opportunity to upgrade to php 7.2, coming from php 5.2 (yeah, I know).

Ever since, the pagination of the /wp-admin/edit.php (posts) is missing in the top right corner, but only for the first page. If I go to /wp-admin/edit.php?paged=2, then it appears again, and it's working as specified.

I am not sure where to look. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: A lot has changed since php 5.2. I would check to make sure all your functionality still works in the new version of php. You can also try going to the permalinks settings and saving that settings form. That will regenerate rewrite rules and htaccess/nginx.conf.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. answered more in detail below the first answer...

Answer (score 0):

I'd first make sure that everything is updated: WP, themes, plugins.

Then I'd look at the plugin's WP page and see how long it's been since they have been updated. You might have some old plugins that could be causing problems, like maybe they are using old JS.

I'd also look at the page source of a couple pages to see if there is anything unexpected (code) in there.

Since the problem is pagination, perhaps your theme is old, and doesn't support new features. Take a look at the error.log file and see if there are errors relating to your theme (or any plugins).

And, perhaps, re-doing the Permalinks page (change it to something else, save it, then change it back to your preference) will 'reset' something.

Whatever it is, report back here so that your solution will help others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Everything was and is updated regularly, we were on all newest plugin versions, except for a few that were necessary but used new php features (mostly [] vs array()). It sure is an old theme (8 years), but it has been maintained by me all the time so there are no errors etc. 

In the new setup we are on all the latest versions. Re-doing the permalinks page did not do the trick, unfortunately, but it was a good idea.

Comment: Can you try a quick switch to a 'twenty' theme then look? Or maybe dig into the generated page source to see if the the pagination is there but hidden by some CSS? Maybe use the Inspector in that area to help narrow down code area and CSS used. Perhaps a CSS conflict somewhere? And, how many posts to display are shown on the Options dropdown for that page (in admin)?